# Converting Array of Arrays to Backbone Collection of Models

Tags: collections, backbone.js, coffeescript, models

new to Backbone and underscore js here.

I have an array of arrays that I want to convert to a collection of models.

So it's like

```
{ {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}
```

The second level of arrays is what's going into a backbone model. Right now, I have

```
collection.reset(_.map(results, (indvidualResults) -> new model(individualResults))
```

Which doesn't work as when I do a console.log(collection.pop) I get a function printed out. I think this is because I'm working with an array of arrays (but I could be wrong). How do I convert the second array into a model and then put that into a collection?

Comment: (1) What does your data really look like? (2) Why are you doing the `_.map` when [`Collection#reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) will do all that for you? (3) Collections have a [`pop` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-pop) so of course `console.log(collection.pop)` gives you a function.

Comment: Do you mean `console.log(collection.pop())`? `console.log(collection.pop)`*should* give you a function.

Answer (score 9):

Reshape your raw data to look more like:

```
[{ first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4 }, { first: 5, second: 6, third: 7, fourth: 8}]
```

Assuming you have a model and collection defined something like:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Model
});
```

Then just pass the array of attribute hashes into the reset method:

```
var results = [{ first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4 }, { first: 5, second: 6, third: 7, fourth: 8}];
var collection = new Collection();
collection.reset(results);
var model = collection.pop();
console.log(JSON.stringify(model.toJSON());
```

Comment: **collection.reset(results);** works fine. But looks like it doesn't execute .parse() method on each model.